# C++ accesing objects far from current class hierarchy

Tags: c++, performance, oop

I think this is a really newb question, but I never found out the answer.  I don't know how exactly to phrase this question, but I often find that I have to access objects that are "far away" from the current object in terms of the current hierarchy.  I just want to make sure that this is the right (only) way to do this.

This goes along with passing parameters in from main also.  I find that some objects far away from main need to be passed in with a parameter multiple times.  How does an object far away from main get information from the command line?

For example for the first case, for 4 classes...

```
class A{
   B b;
   //need to check status of D

   //choice 1
   b.get_c().get_d().get_status();  

   //choice 2
   const C& c = b.get_c();
   const D& d = c.get_d();
   d.get_status();
};

class B{
public:
   C c;
   const C& get_c() {return c;}
};

class C{
public:
   D d;
   const D& get_d() {return d;}
};

class D{
public:
   bool check_status();
};
```

Say something like, A is car, B is door assembly, C is door, D is lock.  Then A has to check say, is lock on, otherwise prevent starting.

Choice 3 is to directly call D's method from A, I'd have to make a few layers of check_status() in C, B, and A and return D, C, B.check_status().

Don't all these calls to subobjects (if the code was a bit more complicated) get a lot of overhead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this sort of question is always the same: Don't worry about it unless and until it becomes a problem, and then, take measurements to decide which option is best. Yes, there's an overhead with calls to subobjects but with the example you've given (and with many real-life examples) this overhead is unavoidable (and the compiler may optimize some of it away anyway).

Answer (score 1):

All those functions are inline, since declared within the class definition, and are simple `return something;`. They return references, so there are no copies involved (note that they should probably be `const` member functions, otherwise I don't see how your code would compile). There should be no overhead at all, I would recommend you compile your code and take a look at the generated assembly just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for symmety you can place in A a `const B& get_b() const` and do

```
get_b().get_c().get_d().get_status();
```

The two choiches are perfectly equivalent (and compiler optimization may in fact produce identical code).

The only suggestion is to declare the getters as `const X& get_x() const`, since they don't modify the owner.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above getting hold of a copy of [Large Scale C++ Software Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Large-Scale-C-Software-Design-APC/dp/0201633620/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1317372536&sr=8-1) may help in this regard. Don't worry that the first chapter is a bit irrelevant these days, the majority of the ideas presented are still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the performance of a chained function call like yours, these days there is not much to worry about when the functions are returning simple const references.

However, as a possible design flaw, you generally should work with the immediate objects and avoid digging deep into other object's data. Figuratively, when you want to know when your merchant has a product available again you ask him directly (`time = merchant.Availability(product);`) and don't ask him for his supply arrival dates (`time = merchant. GetSupplyerForProduct(product). SupplySchedule(). NextArrival();`)